# Code for multiple X input for Y prediction in python?

Tags: python, linear-regression

I do have a question.  I uploaded my own CSV with 2 features called Days and HC, and the y value is Hours.  I trained it but what would be the code I can put to predict Y based on two independent X input?  Let's say I want Days to be 9 and HC to be 20, but this combination is not in any row of the csv file.  I tried the below but it only picks the first row that already has the HC and Days combination to predict the Hours.

X_test[:1]
model.predict(X_test[:1])

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.